# horizontal scroll inside container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm pretty new to javascript and I'm trying to create a horizontal scrolling div :-

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joso157/bpxkdb86/1/)

As you can see the menu links go to each colour but I would like to put this inside a container  which is 250x250px so only 1 colour is visible, then you click on whichever link and it scrolls to that colour.

Hope someone can help me with a few pointers.

Thanks!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollLeft: $(this.hash).offset().left
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.child-element {
    min-width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
}
.child1 {
    background-color: purple;
}
.child2 {
    background-color: orange;
}
.child3 {
    background-color: black;
}
.child4 {
    background-color: green;
}
.child5 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.child6 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#purple" class="scroll">PURPLE</a> 
<a href="#orange" class="scroll">ORANGE</a> 
<a href="#black" class="scroll">BLACK</a> 
<a href="#green" class="scroll">GREEN</a> 
<a href="#blue" class="scroll">BLUE</a> 
<a href="#red" class="scroll">RED</a>

<div class="container">
    <div id="purple" class="child-element child1"></div>
    <div id="orange" class="child-element child2"></div>
    <div id="black" class="child-element child3"></div>
    <div id="green" class="child-element child4"></div>
    <div id="blue" class="child-element child5"></div>
    <div id="red" class="child-element child6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: *Edit* added an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Script47 mentioned, you'll want to apply `overflow-x` as a CSS property to your element, in addition the `width` (to act as a viewport). Here's what your final CSS might look like:

```
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
}
```

After that, you'll need to modify your JS slightly. You'll still want to scroll to the `offset` of the element, but you'll also need to take into account your current `scroll` position.

(To clarify, if you clicked `orange` - which has an offset initially of `250px`, post-animation, the offset for orange would be`0px`, and `black` would be`250px`. If you then click `black`, it will attempt to scroll to `250px`, which is the orange element.)

Here's what the updated JS might look like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
        var current = $('.container').scrollLeft();
        var left = $(this.hash).position().left;        

        event.preventDefault();

        $('.container').animate({
            scrollLeft: current + left
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

A fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/bpxkdb86/4/

For the fiddle, I removed physical `white-space` in the HTML (to prevent the divs from having space between them) using `<!-- comments -->`, and also added `position: relative` to the containing element (to use `position`)

Comment: Exactly what I was attempting to do. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

A `CSS` solution, try adding this to you element in CSS,

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

This, should do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need two changes for this to work.

First, add height and width for the container and then set overflow in css.

```
width:250px;
height:250px;
overflow: auto;
```

Second update jquery to animate the container, now it is animating the body.

```
$('.single-box').animate({
```

JSFiddle is avaialble in the following link

https://jsfiddle.net/jym7q0Lu/

Answer (score 0):

just use a css if you want your div to be scrollable..

```
   .container {
       white-space: nowrap;
       overflow-x: scroll;
       width: 250px;
       position: relative;
  }
```