# Javascript - Make div sliding with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a container around the car pictures, and use `overflow-y: scroll` so I can scroll through them. How can I make it so I have two buttons I can click so I can scroll through them with buttons via javascript or jquery?
[image]

Current html is:

```
<div  class="event_container">

            <a href="/index.php?con=events&id=5">
        <div style="display: inline-block; background-image: url('img/events/event5.jpg')" class="">
            <p>Kør med de store!</p>
            <p>18-01-2017</p>
            <div style="display: inline-block" class="tile"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
                <a href="/index.php?con=events&id=3">
        <div style="display: inline-block; background-image: url('img/events/event3.jpg')" class="">
            <p>Den nye FIAT 500!</p>
            <p>24-01-2017</p>
            <div style="display: inline-block" class="tile"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
                <a href="/index.php?con=events&id=1">
        <div style="display: inline-block; background-image: url('img/events/event1.jpg')" class="">
            <p>Event 1</p>
            <p>30-04-2017</p>
            <div style="display: inline-block" class="tile"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
                <a href="/index.php?con=events&id=2">
        <div style="display: inline-block; background-image: url('img/events/event2.jpg')" class="">
            <p>Test kør bughatti!</p>
            <p>03-06-2017</p>
            <div style="display: inline-block" class="tile"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
                <a href="/index.php?con=events&id=4">
        <div style="display: inline-block; background-image: url('img/events/event4.jpg')" class="">
            <p>Skal du køre suziki?</p>
            <p>30-06-2017</p>
            <div style="display: inline-block" class="tile"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: Have you looked for any slideshow plugins on internet?

Comment: use carousel or slider.

Comment: Recommend slick slider.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Scroll+div+with+JavaScript Also: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Jquery+slide+div+with+buttons

Comment: @andyjones Slick slider looks like what i need, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [horizontal scroll inside container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867646/horizontal-scroll-inside-container)

Answer (score 0):

> I've made a container around the car pictures, and use overflow-y:
>   scroll so I can scroll through them. How can I make it so I have two
>   buttons I can click so I can scroll through them with buttons via
>   javascript or jquery?

Here are 3 approaches using:

- jQuery
- plain javascript
- CSS and javascript

The last approach which uses CSS Transitions delivers the smoothest and best animation.

## Approach 1 (of 3)

You can use jQuery's custom `animate({scrollTop: [value]})` method to scroll the images up and down.

**Working example in jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('button').eq(0).click(function(){
        $('div').animate({scrollTop: $('div').scrollTop() -158 + 'px'});
    });
    
    $('button').eq(1).click(function(){
        $('div').animate({scrollTop: $('div').scrollTop() +158 + 'px'});
    });

});
```

```css
div, img, button {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

div {
width: 596px;
height: 152px;
padding: 12px;
background-color: rgb(63,63,63);
overflow-y: auto;
}

img {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 140px;
margin: 6px 6px 12px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,127,0);
}

img:last-of-type {
margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<img alt="image-1" />
<img alt="image-2" />
<img alt="image-3" />
<img alt="image-4" />
<img alt="image-5" />

<img alt="image-6" />
<img alt="image-7" />
<img alt="image-8" />
<img alt="image-9" />
<img alt="image-10" />

<img alt="image-11" />
<img alt="image-12" />
<img alt="image-13" />
<img alt="image-14" />
<img alt="image-15" />
</div>

<button type="button">Scroll Up</button>
<button type="button">Scroll Down</button>
```

---

## Approach 2 (of 3)

If you want to skip jQuery, here is an alternative version using plain javascript.

**Working example in plain javascript:**

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var imageContainer = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var scrollValue;
var scrollDirection;

function scroll() {
 scrollDirection = (this.textContent === 'Scroll Down' ? 1 : -1);
 scrollValue = (this.textContent === 'Scroll Down' ? 158 : -158);
    var startPoint = imageContainer.scrollTop;

    var scrollDiv = setInterval(function() {
        imageContainer.scrollTop += scrollDirection;
        if (imageContainer.scrollTop === (startPoint + scrollValue)) {
         scrollDirection = 0;
            clearInterval(scrollDiv);
        }
    }, 1);
}

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', scroll, false);
}
```

```css
div, img, button {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

div {
width: 596px;
height: 152px;
padding: 12px;
background-color: rgb(63,63,63);
overflow-y: auto;
}

img {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 140px;
margin: 6px 6px 12px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,127,0);
}

img:last-of-type {
margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img alt="image-1" />
<img alt="image-2" />
<img alt="image-3" />
<img alt="image-4" />
<img alt="image-5" />

<img alt="image-6" />
<img alt="image-7" />
<img alt="image-8" />
<img alt="image-9" />
<img alt="image-10" />

<img alt="image-11" />
<img alt="image-12" />
<img alt="image-13" />
<img alt="image-14" />
<img alt="image-15" />
</div>

<button type="button">Scroll Up</button>
<button type="button">Scroll Down</button>
```

## Approach 3 (of 3)

As you will have noted, the plain javascript approach immediately above comes across as a bit slow and jerky. So in the end (as with all animations), the optimum approach is to deploy some CSS to handle the animation.

**Working example in CSS and plain javascript:**

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var scrollValue;

function scroll() {
 var imageTransformStyle = window.getComputedStyle(images[0]).transform;
 var yStart = (imageTransformStyle.lastIndexOf(',') + 2);
 var yEnd = imageTransformStyle.lastIndexOf(')');
  
 var currentPosition = Number(imageTransformStyle.substring(yStart, yEnd));
 scrollValue = (this.textContent === 'Scroll Down') ? -158 : 158;
 var newPosition = currentPosition + scrollValue;
  
 if (newPosition > 0) {newPosition = 0;}
 if (newPosition < -316) {newPosition = -316;}

 for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
     images[i].style.transform = 'translateY(' + newPosition + 'px)';
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', scroll, false);
}
```

```css
div, img, button {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

div {
width: 578px;
height: 152px;
padding: 12px;
background-color: rgb(63,63,63);
overflow-y: hidden;
}

img {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 140px;
margin: 6px 6px 12px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,127,0);
transform: translateY(0);
transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}

img:last-of-type {
margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img alt="image-1" />
<img alt="image-2" />
<img alt="image-3" />
<img alt="image-4" />
<img alt="image-5" />

<img alt="image-6" />
<img alt="image-7" />
<img alt="image-8" />
<img alt="image-9" />
<img alt="image-10" />

<img alt="image-11" />
<img alt="image-12" />
<img alt="image-13" />
<img alt="image-14" />
<img alt="image-15" />
</div>

<button type="button">Scroll Up</button>
<button type="button">Scroll Down</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make action animated with jQuery to be more comfortable with moved image. Try example below:

```js
var outer = $('.container');

$('#right').click(function() {
   outer.animate({scrollLeft: '+=30px'}, 500);
});

$('#left').click(function() {
   outer.animate({scrollLeft: '-=30px'}, 500);
});

$('#top').click(function() {
   outer.animate({scrollTop: '-=30px'}, 500);
});

$('#bottom').click(function() {
   outer.animate({scrollTop: '+=30px'}, 500);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.inner {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div  class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    A B C D E F G 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    -------------------------------
    9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 A B C D E F G
  </div>
</div>

<button id="left"> < </button><button id="right"> > </button>
  
<button id="top"> ^ </button><button id="bottom"> V </button>
```