# On scroll move image horizontally, then stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can move an image vertically quite easily, but how do I move it horizontally using my method? I would also like the image to stop moving in that direction once I get to a certain point, I have no idea how to do that, perhaps I could change its css to stay in a position once I get so many pixels down.

The code below moves it vertically, can I use a similar simple method to move the image horizontally?

**CODE:**

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('.planeImg').css({'transform' : 'translate(-50%, -'+ wScroll /2 +'%)'})

});


.planeImg {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   background: url("../images/plane.png");
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   z-index: 99;
   height: 80px;
   width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31867832/2565294)?

Comment: I suggest you use `Scroll()` directly .

Comment: you can try $('.planeImg').css({'transform' : 'translate( -'+ wScroll /2 +'%, -50%)'})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked well.

```
$('.planeImg').css({'transform' : 'translate( -'+ wScroll /2 +'%, -50%)'})
```